# How to specify pypy as an interpreter in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pypy

I downloaded window binary on pypy.org and evething be ok, pypy3.exe perfectly run in my window computer. However, I want to add pypy as an interpreter in pycharm. Unfortunately, there was an error when pycharm create virtualenv. The massage of the error is: "Directory C://.../venv/bin/python does not found". I fixed it by renaming 2 file pypy3.exe and pypy3w.exe, it becomes python.exe and pythonw.exe respectively. And this error is fixed. But I get another error, the message is:"no such file or directory: 'c:\users\asus\pycharmprojects\pypy\venv\site-packages\test-easy-install-12584.write-test' the installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was: c:\users\asus\pycharmprojects\pypy\venv\site-packages\ this directory does not currently exist. please create it and try again, or choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir option). How can i fix that?. I use pypy3.6 v7.3.0 and pycharm 2019.3

Comment: Seemingly related: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006939619-Failed-to-create-interpreter-venv-bin-python-not-found.

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html?_ga=2.48805295.849890943.1585198011-1589269666.1585198011#)? Especially the part about "Choose the base interpreter from the list, or click ... and find a Python executable in the your file system"

Comment: I did. It works with the official version from python.org (CPython), but not work with pypy